# Typescript Cannot find module 'wnumb'

Tags: typescript, riot.js, tsd

```
/// <amd-module name="AdvancedSlider"/>
import * as $ from "jquery";
import * as Wnumb from "wnumb"; 
//also tried import {wNumb} from "wnumb"
//and tried import {wNumb} from "wNumb"

export class AdvancedSlider extends Riot.Element { ...blah ... }
```

This results in `Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'wnumb'.`

However, if I do:

```
/// <amd-module name="AdvancedSlider"/>
import * as $ from "jquery";
import "wnumb";
export class AdvancedSlider extends Riot.Element { ...blah ... }
```

It compiles.

Using the typings from https://github.com/retyped/wnumb-tsd-ambient/blob/master/wnumb.d.ts  I need to do the former because I need to get a handle to it in the AdvancedSlider class.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit 2 August 2016**

Couldn't get it to work.

Used:

```
const wNumb = require("wnumb");
```

Which seems like a fail to me. Moving on...

Answer (score 1):

As late as it is, I ran into the same problem as you :(

I am however using webapck 2.x, anyway this might help the next person to come but I got it to work by using the webpack ProvidePlugin:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
       $: "jquery",
       jQuery: "jquery",
       wNumb: "wnumb"
   })
```

Also have the typings from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Hope it works for anyone else.